# What type and thickness of glass to use for floor over stairs?

Tags: flooring, glass

We have created a new loft room and over the already built stairs, the covering over the deepest part of the stairs is a plywood covering.  I would like to replace this with glass that will be tough and strong enough to stand on.

- For this purpose should I use a special type of glass, if so which?
- Also what would be the recommended thickness of glass to use? This will not be a regular thoroughfare just needs to take the weight of a person.
- The last question is how should this be mounted, with glue/silicone/putty or screwed/bolted to a wooden frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you want to put the glass. Landing? Tread? What span is it between studs? 16"?
You are probably looking at a 3/4" laminated tempered glass.  Your best bet would be to call your local glass shop.  They will know what the best product at the best price would be.

Comment: I would paint the floor joists then use clear silicone

Comment: even better if you paint the floor joists clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the possibility of using Lexan, it can be drilled if needed for securing, but you would need to talk to their engineers to figure the thickness that would work. I think with a 16" center framing that 3/4"thick would work, but I can't say for sure since I am not engineer.

The reason I spec Lexan, is to remove the possibility of the small chance something metallic will drop and shatter the tempered glass. That is all it would take. Otherwise, I have seen tempered glass do some incredible things, but holding up to a small ding left by the corner of something hard is not one of them....

Answer (score 1):

Use bulletproof glass. It's designed to withstand stress. Don't use laminated glass. It is susceptible to chipping. Bulletproof isn't because it's not actual glass; it's more like plexiglass or Lexan™.

Answer (score 1):

Using glass on a walking surface is not recommended due to slipping. Having said that you could use glass tile and a clear silicon adhesive.